# Cant load Japasnese font from CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I am trying to load a font from in a WordPress site, but the follow error is happening:

OTS parsing error: glyf: Failed to parse glyph 413

What could be the problem?

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: "Elegant";
    src: url(./fonts/‚¦‚Ê‚ª‚Ñ‚ÆW3-´‰¹.TTF) format("TrueType");
 }

.site-title a {
    color: #1c1c1c;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Elegant";
}
```

Comment: Have you load the font from function.php enquee script!!! One more thing is that name '|£€¥*%=#' in the file...sounds like a hacked font.

Comment: I am trying to load from CSS. I also tryed to display the font name correctly, its a Japanese font.

Comment: The font name should be: Elegant W7-Seion Medium

Answer (score -2):

Set these values in php ini.

413 for large file errors i think.

```
memory_limit = 120M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
max_execution_time = 300
```

may be it will help you

Comment: You mean, change the server`s PHP config?

Comment: Yes.. or you can set it from your php page too using ini_set()